# Class VS HashMap for more than 50 fields from file

Tags: java, performance, oop, hashmap

I have a huge file which has around 60 columns separated by a delimiter. It has more than 1000 records.

I have another file which has only two columns of which has one common column between two files. I want to do a inner join kind of manipulation in java between two files based on the column and combine the records.

Class object with 60 fields(POJO for each file) or HashMap for each file. which would be the best design decision to load the information from these two files for manipulation? or any other suggestion?

Comment: Have you considered a multidimensional array? It will have much faster insert and remove time. It of course assumes that the order of the columns stays the same

Comment: @ASKASK: MultiDimensional array is a good one to consider as well.

Comment: Load it into memory, and I'd prefer custom POJOs. Of course, you can have one key and one value pojo in a Map. Or just a TreeSet of value(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am not getting what you mean by one key and one value pojo. Could you please elaborate

Comment: @user2364770 `Map<KeyPojo, ValuePojo> map = new HashMap<>();` KeyPojo should override `hashCode` and `equals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a huge file which has around 60 columns separated by a delimiter. It has more than 1000 records.

To me, 60k doesn't sound like something performance-critical.

> Class object with 60 fields(POJO for each file) or HashMap for each file. which would be the best design decision to load the information from these two files for manipulation? or any other suggestion?

Objects build as maps are a terrible thing. Very flexible and completely type-unsafe. Something I wouldn't use except in extreme cases.

This might be such a case. If you don't use the lines for anything else, then you don't need the objects. You don't even need the map. Using a 2D array feels simpler and faster. You should encapsulate it in a class for more sanity; you can add methods like like `getInt(int row, String name)` or better `getInt(int row, MyColumnId columnId)` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using HashMap/TreeMap with a specified Key and a value as 'Java object class'. Each Java object class can have required fields which are set or retrieved using getter setter method should help.